# Error in saving LWC html file

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Error in saving LWC html file:

missing matching tag for `<lightnig-card>` although i have already created this tag,

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Simple Calculator">
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                        <lightning-input label="Enter input 1" onchange={value1} ></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                        <lightning-input label="Enter input 2" onchange={value2}></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">
                        <lightning-button label="Add" onclick={displaySum} ></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button label="Subtract"></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button label="multiply"></lightning-button>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        <template if:true={displaySumjs}>
                        <div> Sum of {input1} and {input2} is = {result} </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout> 
      </lightning-card>  
         </template>
```

Comment: What actual error message are you getting?

Comment: "message": "[Line: 18, Col: 1] LWC1511: Missing matching tag for <lightning-card>",
 "

Comment: When this error message is coming? While deployment or saving?

Comment: while saving in VS code. Code is not compiling due to this error.

Comment: You can update these information into your question.

Comment: @Suren I tried your code, and I deployed it without error. The problem may come from another file. Close others opened files and check if you don’t have any comma, semicolon elsewhere in your file.

Comment: @Klecool yes, I deleted html file and created another file pasted same code. worked fine. Dont know what was the issue but same code is working good.